# Консольный TCP-чат

Tags: c#, tcp, tcp-ip

Нашёл пример консольного TCP чата он состоит из 2-х консольных проектов. Первый проект это сервер он содержит классы ServerObject, ClientObject и Program. Второй проект это клиент, он содержит только класс Program. Но у меня появились кое какие вопросы на которые я так и не смог ответить.
Если я правильно понял передача данных всем клиентам осуществляется с помощью метода BroadcastMessage(), где вызывается метод Stream.Write куда в качестве параметров передаётся сообщение преобразованное в массив data типа byte и его длина, но не понятно зачем туда ещё передаётся 0? И ещё как узнать размер получаемого сообщения? 
Проект сервера - Класс ServerObject:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChatServer
{
    public class ServerObject
    {
        static TcpListener tcpListener; // сервер для прослушивания
        List<ClientObject> clients = new List<ClientObject>(); // все подключения

        protected internal void AddConnection(ClientObject clientObject)
        {
            clients.Add(clientObject);
        }
        protected internal void RemoveConnection(string id)
        {
            // получаем по id закрытое подключение
            ClientObject client = clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            // и удаляем его из списка подключений
            if (client != null)
                clients.Remove(client);
        }
        // прослушивание входящих подключений
        protected internal void Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
                tcpListener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(tcpClient, this);
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
                    clientThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Disconnect();
            }
        }

        // трансляция сообщения подключенным клиентам
        protected internal void BroadcastMessage(string message, string id)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
            {
                if (clients[i].Id!= id) // если id клиента не равно id отправляющего
                {
                    clients[i].Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //передача данных
                }
            }
        }
        // отключение всех клиентов
        protected internal void Disconnect()
        {
            tcpListener.Stop(); //остановка сервера

            for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
            {
                clients[i].Close(); //отключение клиента
            }
            Environment.Exit(0); //завершение процесса
        }
    }
}
```

Проект сервера - Класс ClientObject:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ChatServer
{
    public class ClientObject
    {
        protected internal string Id { get; private set; }
        protected internal NetworkStream Stream {get; private set;}
        string userName;
        TcpClient client;
        ServerObject server; // объект сервера

        public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient, ServerObject serverObject)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            client = tcpClient;
            server = serverObject;
            serverObject.AddConnection(this);
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            try
            {
                Stream = client.GetStream();
                // получаем имя пользователя
                string message = GetMessage();
                userName = message;

                message = userName + " вошел в чат";
                // посылаем сообщение о входе в чат всем подключенным пользователям
                server.BroadcastMessage(message, this.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                // в бесконечном цикле получаем сообщения от клиента
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        message = GetMessage();
                        message = String.Format("{0}: {1}", userName, message);
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        server.BroadcastMessage(message, this.Id);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        message = String.Format("{0}: покинул чат", userName);
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        server.BroadcastMessage(message, this.Id);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // в случае выхода из цикла закрываем ресурсы
                server.RemoveConnection(this.Id);
                Close();
            }
        }

        // чтение входящего сообщения и преобразование в строку
        private string GetMessage()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = 0;
            do
            {
                bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (Stream.DataAvailable);

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        // закрытие подключения
        protected internal void Close()
        {
            if (Stream != null)
                Stream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Проект сервера- Класс Program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChatServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static ServerObject server; // сервер
        static Thread listenThread; // потока для прослушивания
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                server = new ServerObject();
                listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Listen));
                listenThread.Start(); //старт потока
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                server.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проект клиента - Класс Program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ChatClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static string userName;
        private const string host = "127.0.0.1";
        private const int port = 8888;
        static TcpClient client;
        static NetworkStream stream;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите свое имя: ");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();
            client = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                client.Connect(host, port); //подключение клиента
                stream = client.GetStream(); // получаем поток

                string message = userName;
                byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                // запускаем новый поток для получения данных
                Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
                receiveThread.Start(); //старт потока
                Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать, {0}", userName);
                SendMessage();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Disconnect();
            }
        }
        // отправка сообщений
        static void SendMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите сообщение: ");

            while (true)
            {
                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        // получение сообщений
        static void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (stream.DataAvailable);

                    string message = builder.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(message);//вывод сообщения
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Подключение прервано!"); //соединение было прервано
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        static void Disconnect()
        {
            if(stream!=null)
                stream.Close();//отключение потока
            if(client!=null)
                client.Close();//отключение клиента
            Environment.Exit(0); //завершение процесса
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно `MSDN`, `Stream.Write` 2м параметром принимает `offset`, т.е. отступ от начала.

```
public abstract void Write(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

К примеру, если вы укажите не на начало строки, а на ее середину, то будут переданы не полные данные.
Обычно его используют для передачи частичных данных, или же как пример, если сообщение было передано не полностью, то мы можем передать его остаток.

Comment: Спасибо. Не подскажите как узнать размер отправляемого сообщения?

Comment: `byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);` полное сообщение, а его длина, это `data.Length` соответственно.

Comment: Я имел в виду какой размер сообщения в байтах?

Comment: Я не вижу код клиента, поэтому не могу вам дать точный ответ.

Comment: Добавил весь код программы

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев, ну так вот, теперь смотрите метод `SendMessage`, там идет в цикле считывание ввода консоли, после чего преобразование строки в массив байтов, в котором и берется длина ровно так же как показал выше.

Comment: Значит размер массива( в байтах) равен его длине?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев, естественно.